# How to setup Eclipse Plugin Profiler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, profiler

I want to use the Eclipse Plugin Profiler to profile my applications. However, I am facing problems while installing it. I copied the unzipped folder of the profiler into the plugins folder in the root eclipse folder. However when i open eclipse, run->run configurations-> and click on profiler, i receive the following error:

"An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
ru/nlmk/eclipse/plugins/profiler/launch/ProfilerTab"

I think there is a problem in the location of the profiler dll, but i don't know where to put it.

How do i make this plugin work? thank you in advance

Comment: I am not able to access the error log, it keeps telling me that such location does not exist...I just want to know the right steps for installing the profiler plugin on eclipse. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The *right* steps for installation are defined at http://eclipsecolorer.sourceforge.net/index_profiler.html, and the DLL should be in your `bin` folder of your JRE installation.

Comment: Hi I am also having same problem above steps didn't worked for me

Comment: What problems are you having @ashokk?

Comment: "An error has occurred. See error log for more details. ru/nlmk/eclipse/plugins/profiler/launch/ProfilerTab"